# Why aren't the expect statements called?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, ngrx

I am currently struggling a little bit with writing unit test for NgRx effects.

This is my effect:

```js
navigateToProjectOnInvokeJoinProject$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(invokeJoinProjectSuccess),
        // On reload, projectId is already available. In that case, don't navigate again
        concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(selectProjectIdFromRoute)),
        filter(([_, projectId]) => !projectId),
        map(([action, _]) => this.projectDetailsService.initialNavigateToProject(action.projectId))
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

This is the test:

```js
it("should call initialNavigateToProject if project is not opened yet", () => {
      const action = invokeJoinProjectSuccess({ projectId, activeUsers: [] });

      jest.spyOn(projectDetailsService, "initialNavigateToProject");

      actions$ = of(action);

      effects.navigateToProjectOnInvokeJoinProject$.subscribe(() => {
        expect(projectDetailsService.initialNavigateToProject).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(projectDetailsService.initialNavigateToProject).toHaveBeenCalledWith(projectId);
      });
    });
```

It passes, but only because the expect statements aren't actually called at all. I put `expect(1).toEqual(2)` there to make sure and the test was still green, which is of course impossible.

To mock the `ProjectDetailsService`, i use `MockProvider` of the `ng-mocks` library and then setup the TestBed with `projectDetailsService = TestBed.inject(ProjectDetailsService);`

What am I missing here?

I tried to spy on the service method that is called in the effect and was expecting it to be triggered but apparently it's not. Or rather, the subscribe block isn't even entered.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this to be because of the `concatLatestFrom` and `filter`. I suppose they return a falsy value, which stops the stream.

To fix this, you can setup the store with an initial value so it continues.

Take a look at the `done` callback so that this test will fail in its current state. https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks

Or, I prefer to create an array with actions and use the array for my expect statements, for an example see https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project#e1aedff7251a2ccd78cb118e42f7f2e2